How can I send data from JavaScript to Python Streamlit using postMessage?
Parent Code ( VSCode Extension Webview Code )
    private renderHtml(): string {
    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
              <head>
                  <meta charset="UTF-8">
                  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="${this._chatStyle}">
              </head>
              <body>
                  <iframe id="chatView" src="${url}"></iframe>
                  <script type="module" src="${this._chatSrc}"></script>
              </body>
              <script>
                  window.param = ${param};
              </script>
       </html>`;
    } 

this._chatSrc ( ChatView.js )
    const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
    const iframe = document.getElementById('chatView');
    iframe.onload = () => {
      const iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
      iframeWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(window.param, null, 2), '*');
    };

    const handleMessage = event => {
      console.log('Received message:', event.data);
    };

    window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);

Child Code( Python Streamlit )
from openai import OpenAI
import streamlit as st
js = """
<script>
    window.addEventListener("message", (evt) => {
        console.log('call')    
    });
    window.parent.parent.postMessage("Some data", '*');
</script>
"""
st.components.v1.html(js, height=0)

When I use window.addEventListener
in Streamlit, it doesn't seem to trigger. How can I receive data from the parent window in Streamlit using an event listener?
